# Converting Graph3D to Graphics3D

Tags: graphs-and-networks, graphics3d

How you do convert a Graph3D (or GraphPlot3D) into Graphics3D?

```
Graphics3D@ButterflyGraph[3]
```

[image]

```
Show[Graph3D@ButterflyGraph[3], ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False, ViewAngle -> Automatic, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 300, Background -> Black]
```

[image]

**Update:**

What confuses me is that changing the `ViewPoint` seems to kill the styling:

```
Show[Graph3D@ButterflyGraph[3], ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `Show`

```
bg = ButterflyGraph[3];
Show[Graph3D @ bg]

Head[%]
```

> Graphics3D

```
g3d = Graph3D[ButterflyGraph[3], ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, 
   SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False, ViewAngle -> Automatic, 
   BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 300, Background -> Black];
Head /@ {g3d, Show[g3d]}
```

> {Graph, Graphics3D}

```
Row[{g3d, Show[g3d]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I tried that but using Show seemed to kill the style (see updated screenshot). Try `Show[Graph3D@ButterflyGraph[3], ViewPoint -> Front]` does this maintain `Graph3D`'s default blue vertices for you?

Comment: @M.R, probably version/os-related. In version 11.3 (windows 10/84) it works fine.

Comment: @M.R. if you look at the options of the Graphics3D that is returned by Show, you see it has a directional lighting source.  This interacts poorly with your viewpoint.  To workaround, give the option `Lighting -> "Neutral"` along with the view point.